# Where is the datewidget in my wagtail formbuilder?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am implementing an AbstractEmailForm using wagtail form builder. The date-widget is not showing in the date-field. Is this a current bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Which date field are you referring to? Is this in the Wagtail Admin interface (eg. when editing a form page in wagtail admin, clicking 'field type' does not show the 'Date' in the dropdown). It might be helpful to update the question with your actual model definition (eg. class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):...)

Answer (score 0):

Wagtail doesn't provide a date chooser widget for forms rendered on your site front-end, as that would involve inserting custom Javascript onto your template - something that Wagtail makes a point of not doing (since the contents of the template should always be under your control).

You're free to install your own preferred date chooser component, such as the [jQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), and apply it to the form field with a line of code such as:

```
$('input#id_date').datepicker()
```